# "The Grand Inquisitor" book cover - what does cyrillic letters stand for?

Tags: литература, алфавит

I recently bought a copy of, "The Grand Inquisitor" and, after a few days, I noticed that the title of the book on front cover was written partially in cyrillic. [image: Here is a photo of it.] Does the cyrillic on the front mean anything or is it just for aesthetic purposes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means nothing. It just reads "The Grand Inquisitor" in English with a few Cyrillic letters thrown in to replace English letters that they look vaguely similar to. This is an example of [Faux Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faux_Cyrillic).

For what it's worth, these are the letters used:

д - used for the "a" in "grand", actually represents /d/

и - used for the "n" in "grand", actually represents /i/

б - used for the "d" in "grand", actually represents /b/

ф - used for the "q" in "inquisitor", actually represents /f/

Comment: "it" looks like "П"; "u" is "Ч".

Comment: Yeah...  And "*п*" is "n", and "o" is "о".

Comment: "Faux Cyrillic". Didn't know it had a name. Always make me cringe.

Comment: This cover is annoying in so many ways.